# Is there a TwoColoring function of Graph object?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, packages

The following code shows the `GraphUtilities` package makes a problem for `Graph` object.
I want to use  a `TwoColoring` function without using the `GraphUtilities` package. 
Is there a `TwoColoring` function of `Graph` object ?
*Mathematica* version is 9.0.1.0.

```
g1 = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3};

GraphPlot[g1, VertexLabeling -> True, ImageSize -> 200]    

Graph[g1, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20]    

Needs["GraphUtilities`"]    
gc = ToCombinatoricaGraph[g1]    
color = TwoColoring[gc]    

GraphPlot[g1, 
         VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Text[Framed[#2, Background -> Hue[color[[#3]]/4], 
         FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0.94, 0.85, 0.36]], #1]} &)]    

color2 = Position[color, 2][[1]] 

HighlightGraph[Graph[g1, VertexLabels -> "Name"], {2}, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

> ```
> HighlightGraph[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name"], {2}, 
>                                          ImagePadding -> 20]
> ```

No graphics.

Answer (score 1):

If you load GraphUtilities, context of Graph will be changed to Combinatorica (from System).  If you want to use system Graph (when GraphUtilities or Combinatorica loaded), you have to specify System` context.  For example,

```
HighlightGraph[System`Graph[g1, VertexLabels -> "Name"], {2}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

will work.

There is no TwoColoring function for Graph, but you can easily write one using BreadthFirstScan:

```
twoColoring[g_?BipartiteGraphQ]:=
  GatherBy[Reap[
      BreadthFirstScan[g, 
        "DiscoverVertex" -> (Sow[{#1, Mod[#3, 2, 1]}] &)]][[2, 1]], 
  Last][[All, All, 1]]

twoColoring[g_] := {}
```

I make output as two sets but you could modify it whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. Your twoColoring function is what I am looking for. Y.Sato